# How can I tell what my current coordinates are?

Tags: subnautica

I was exploring the new Alien Research Facility that was some ~1200m below the ocean with my PRAWN Suit.  I entered the facility with my PRAWN and exited it to walk around.  Unfortunately, there appears to be a bug that allows you to get out of your PRAWN when you are too close to a wall, leaving you stuck inside the wall.

I know there is a teleport command (`warp`) that you supply the X, Y, and Z coordinates you would like to teleport to.  In this case, I wanted to teleport a few Z's forward to get out of the wall.  How can you tell what your current coordinates are?

Comment: Z is Up/Down, Y is North/South, X is East/West

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, you can open a debugger that supplies you with a bunch of stats about the game. One of the stats is "Camera world pos" which has numbers after it. These numbers are the X, Y, and Z coordinates (respectively) of the player's camera view (which is basically your current position).

Comment: X is East/West, Y is North/South and Z is depth